# How to prove $a$ is the product of $2$ irreducibles in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$ such that $N(a)=pq$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes.

Show that 1) $a$ cannot be written as a product of more than $2$ irreducibles.

2) $a$ has to be the product of two irreducibles.

For 1) I wrote:

Suppose $a=p_1p_2...p_n$ for some $n>2$ with $p_i$ being irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ then $N(a)=N(p_1)...N(p_n) \implies pq=N(p_1)...N(p_n)$ but then we must have $1=N(p_1)...N(p_{j-1})N(p_{j+1})...N(p_{i-1})N(p_{i+1})...N(p_n)$ (simply dividing the $p,q$ out). But then since all the norms are bigger than or equal zero we must get the remaining norms are $1$ then the rest of the factors of $a$ remaining are units so they are by definition not reducible. Hence we can't write $a$ as a product of more than two irreducibles.

For 2) though I am stuck and would like some advice. If I can show it can't be written as a product of one irreducible I am done so suppose $a$ is irreducible then...(I also have the fact that if $a$ is irreducible then $a$ is prime but I can't see how to use that.)

Comment: Let $\pi$ be a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ dividing $p$. a) What is $N(\pi)$, b) what relation is there between $\pi$ and $a$?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Another way of looking at Daniel's hint: If $N(a)=pq$ what can you say about the norm of $z=\gcd(a,p)$? Remember that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain. Also remember that $N(p)=p^2$.